# Get specific data from json output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, url

I'm using this code to get specific data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests as req
import json


with open("query4.txt", "r") as f_input:
     # content = f_input.read()
     # a = content[:].split(',')
     for id in f_input:

     # data = {'coordinates': '38.48511505, 48.94205856' '|' '38.49207300, 48.94167600', 'profile': 'driving-car'}
          url = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62483bc257e622284e54ae3004682db1a018&coordinates={}&profile=driving-car".format(id.strip())
          resp = req.get(url, headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8'})
          print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)
          print(resp.url)
          print(resp.text)
```

How can I write the output which is looking like this

```
{"routes":[{"summary":{"distance":388.6,"duration":49.3},"geometry_format":"encodedpolyline","geometry":"uqjrHegz{Dm@r@cCx@Fh@IB}A^{A`@OBuA\\MDgAZI@DeA]B","segments":[{"distance":388.6,"duration":49.3,"steps":[{"distance":107.1,"duration":19.3,"type":11,"instruction":"Head northwest","name":"","way_points":[0,2]},{"distance":15.2,"duration":3.7,"type":0,"instruction":"Turn left","name":"","way_points":[2,3]},{"distance":225.2,"duration":13.5,"type":1,"instruction":"Turn right onto Головатого вулиця","name":"Головатого вулиця","way_points":[3,11]},{"distance":25.1,"duration":9,"type":1,"instruction":"Turn right","name":"","way_points":[11,12]},{"distance":16.1,"duration":3.9,"type":0,"instruction":"Turn left","name":"","way_points":[12,13]},{"distance":0,"duration":0,"type":10,"instruction":"Arrive at your destination, on the right","name":"","way_points":[13,13]}]}],"way_points":[0,13],"bbox":[30.940011,50.358194,30.941469,50.361127]}],"bbox":[30.940011,50.358194,30.941469,50.361127],"info":{"attribution":"openrouteservice.org | OpenStreetMap contributors","engine":{"version":"5.0.1","build_date":"2019-05-29T14:22:56Z"},"service":"routing","timestamp":1568132624542,"query":{"profile":"driving-car","preference":"fastest","coordinates":[[30.941423,50.358173],[30.940412,50.361131]],"language":"en","units":"m","geometry":true,"geometry_format":"encodedpolyline","instructions_format":"text","instructions":true,"elevation":false}}}
```

To a file with data only from the summary: distance in text format?
Thank You!

Comment: Do a json.loads(response), it will be a dict, so iterate o extract your desired key.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "JSON input output" and "Python text file", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 2):

if the result is in a text format you need to convert it into a dict first:

```
result = json.loads(resp.text)
```

And after that you get from the dict the info you need:

```
with open("result.txt", "w") as f_o:
    for row in result["routes"]:
        f_o.write("distance:" + str(row["summary"]["distance"])) # depending on how do you want the result
```

Comment: I want to take from summary only distance in txt format like
distance: 500.2
distance: 231.6
distance: 439.1
every distance on new line

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov I added the key that you need in the iteration (row["summary"]["distance"])

Comment: Thank you, i will try it

Comment: I did your code, but the output were only one row with distance

Comment: Than there is only a row in the JSON. Try to print result["routes"]

Comment: This is a different output for each request, it's like response status, url and then JSON row. And for each request JSON row is different